# Solution verification: proof that the supremum of a set of cardinals is a cardinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, ordinals

I'm trying to show that *if $X$ is a set of cardinals, then $\sup X$ is a cardinal*.

This is part (ii) of Lemma 3.4 in the third edition of Jech on page 29.

The proof in Jech is pretty terse and I don't really understand it.

Here's the proof in Jech.

> Let $\alpha = \sup X$. If $f$ is a one-to-one mapping of $\alpha$ onto some $\beta < \alpha$, let $\kappa \in X$ be such that $\beta < \kappa \le \alpha$. Then $\left|\kappa\right| = \left|\left\{ f(\xi) : \xi < \kappa  \right\}\right| \le \beta$, a contradiction. Thus $\alpha$ is a cardinal.

I have read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192387/) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661333/the-supremum-of-any-set-of-cardinals-considered-as-a-set-of-ordinals-is-again), but I still don't really understand the standard proof. (I'm writing this with the assumption that Jech and those two questions are all referencing a proof that's essentially the same)

I attempted to prove this fact myself contrapositively below and I have two questions about it:

1. Is it valid?
2. Does it differ substantially from the standard proof?

---

Construe $X$ as a set of ordinals.

By way of contrapositive, we want to show that if $\sup X$ is a non-cardinal ordinal (NCO), then X contains at least one NCO.

Let $\kappa$ be $\left|\sup X\right|$.

Observe that $X$ does not contain any $\alpha$ where $\left|\alpha\right| > \kappa$, if it did $\sup X$ would have a cardinality that's too great.

Let $X'$ be $\{ \alpha \in X : \left|\alpha\right| = \kappa \}$.

If $X'$ is empty, then $\sup X \le \kappa$, which is a contradiction.

Suppose $X'$ is a singleton. If $\cup X'$ is a cardinal, then $\sup X$ is a cardinal, which is a contradiction. If $\cup X'$ is a NCO, then $X$ contains a NCO as desired.

Suppose $X'$ contains at least two elements. Then at least one element is a NCO, so $X$ contains at least one NCO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll break down Jech's proof, as once you understand his proof I believe your question will be answered.

Let Card be the Proper class of all cardinals, and X be a set.

Theorem:

If X $\subset$ Card, then sup(X)$\in$Card

Proof:

Assume

X $\subset$ Card

Remark: by a similar theorem ( which you should prove)

If X $\subset$ Ord then sup(X)$\in$Ord

Thus, sup(X)=α$\in$Ord

We will show that α is also a Cardinal.

Assume (RAA) that α is not a cardinal,

So $\exists$β$\in$α(β ≈ α)

i.e. there exists a bijection from α to β

Let f:α $\to$ β, be such a bijection

As α is the least upper bound of X and β < α

β is not an upper bound of X

Thus we can find κ$\in$X s.t.

β < κ ≤ α

As κ is a Cardinal |κ| > |β|

But

rang(f) = β

and

rang($f\restriction_κ$) = { f(δ) | δ$\in$κ} $\subset$ rang(f)

Notice that |κ| = |rang($f\restriction_κ$)| ≤ |rang(f)|

And so κ ≤ |β| < κ

κ < κ

A contradiction

Comment: What does ↾κ mean?

Comment: Domain restriction. If dom(f) = A and B $\subset$ A, then $f\restriction_B$ = { (x,y) | x$\in$B and (x,y)$\in$f}

Comment: I think I got it. If the supremum is a non-cardinal ordinal, then we have another strictly earlier ordinal $\beta$ that's the same size as our supremum. There's gotta be a cardinal $\kappa$ in $X$ that's strictly greater than our earlier ordinal. However $\kappa$ is also a subset of the supremum, and $f$ is a bijection, so $|f[\kappa]| = \kappa$ and thus $\kappa$ is also less than or equal to our earlier ordinal.

Comment: Excellent!! Very good! I'll just add that it's important to highlight that cardinals have strictly larger cardinality than their elements, as that's the main property we use to derive the contradiction. There is greater w.r.t. to elementhood, and greater w.r.t. cardinality, I just want to make that unambiguous if it wasnt clear. Its just with cardinals, |κ| = κ, so I tend to omit the cardinality symbols

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\alpha$ is not a cardinal. Then $\alpha$ is equinumerous to some $\beta<\alpha$. Let $\gamma \in X$ be such that $\beta<\gamma$. Then

$$|\alpha|=|\beta|\leq \beta <\gamma =|\gamma|\leq |\alpha|$$

a contradiction.